# Command not found go — on Mac after installing Go

Tags: macos, go, zsh

I installed go1.5.2 darwin/amd64, but when I run the command `go version`, I get an error in the terminal `zsh: command not found: go`.

I added the path `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` to the bash profile, but I still get the error (I restarted the terminal btw).

I uninstalled and reinstalled, but no luck.

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Comment: I am using zsh in the command line.

Comment: should be adding your `PATH` variable to `~/.zshrc` and not bash profile, the error shows you are using `zsh` and not bash

Comment: You should do `echo $PATH` to see whether your PATH include `/usr/local/go/bin`.  If not, you've not edited the correct file, or not edited all the relevant files.

Comment: @bjhaid, this worked, thank you so much.  I'm assuming if i want to add a workspace path, I need to add this to zshrc file as well.  Is this correct?

Comment: @medev21 I don't know how go tooling works, so I can't answer that question

Comment: @medev21 Go doesn't have the workspaces in the way Python might. Better is to use a tool like http://getgb.io/ which helps tackle this problem better.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Like [bjhaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020958/bjhaid) mentioned in the comments above:

This is happening because you must add your `PATH` to your `~/.zshrc` file.

in the `~/.zshrc` you should add the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

you should then source you `.zshrc` file:

```
. ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I have added the only line which worked for me

Comment: In my case `$GOPATH` wasn't explicitly set so doing `$ echo $GOPATH` returned nothing.
In my `.zshrc` I had to make the second `export` be `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/go/bin` for things to work.

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin` should be `export GOPATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`

Answer (score 24):

I kept running into issues and followed the steps on here and finally got a working solution: http://totzyuta.github.io/blog/2015/06/21/installing-go-by-homebrew-on-mac-os-x/

Install w/brew:

```
brew install golang
```

Edit bash_profile and add following paths:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile

export GOROOT=/usr/local/opt/go/libexec
export GOPATH=$HOME/.go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Source it:

`source ~/.bash_profile`

Then restart terminal

`go version`

Output: go version go1.12 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 7):

For bash, you should edit the `.bashrc` file and add the abobe mentioned line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Answer (score 7):

Add *Go* PATH to your ~/.zshrc file. Open file to edit as -

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

in the *~/.zshrc* you should add the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Once done, close and reopen terminal and you are good to go. For test, you can do -

```
go version
```

It will show output something like -

```
go version go1.15.1 darwin/amd64
```

Comment: this is a duplicate answer

Comment: @ScottStensland Other answers with `.zshrc` and `GOPATH` didn't work with my new installation version `1.18.2`, anyways this answer worked, thank you @Pankaj!

Answer (score 6):

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file at the end on your Mac

`alias go="/usr/local/go/bin/go"`

And in the `Terminal`

`source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` in an existing terminal session. Or to see the new changes you can also re-open a new terminal session.

Answer (score 4):

The `GOPATH` environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. If no `GOPATH` is set, it is assumed to be `$HOME/go` on Unix systems and `%USERPROFILE%\go` on Windows. If you want to use a custom location as your workspace, you can set the `GOPATH` environment variable.

This answer explains how to set this variable on various Unix systems.

`GOPATH` can be any directory on your system. In Unix examples, we will set it to `$HOME/go` (the default since Go 1.8). Note that `GOPATH` must not be on the same path as your Go installation. Another common setup is to set `GOPATH=$HOME`.

### Go 1.13+

```sh
go env -w GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

### Bash

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` to add the following line:

```sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Save and exit your editor. Then, source your `~/.bash_profile`.

```sh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

### Zsh

Edit your `~/.zshrc` file to add the following line:

```sh
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

Save and exit your editor. Then, source your `~/.zshrc`.

```sh
source ~/.zshrc
```

### fish

```sh
set -x -U GOPATH $HOME/go
```

The `-x` is used to specify that this variable should be exported
and the `-U` makes this a universal variable, available to all sessions and
persistent.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i did on my mac:

opened the file `~/.zshrc` using 
`sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
then pasted

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`
save and exit(ctrl + s, ctrl + x then press y)
then ran

`. ~/.zshrc`
go was up and running, 
verified by typing just go in command line.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was not having ~/.`zshrc` profile file. Followed below steps to make it work.

Mac os version : Mojave (10.14.6)

Go version : go1.13.1 `darwin`/`amd64`

Reference link : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-go-programming-language-on-mac-os-x/

As mentioned in link, when i was executing "go env" command, it was throwing error "go command not found". Adding "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin" in "~/.`bashrc`" profile file didn't do any magic!!

step 1 : Create .`zshrc` profile under home path.

$ cd /User/xxxx
(Eg : /User/`tapan`)

$ touch .`zshrc`

step 2 : append 'PATH' with go in .`zshrc` file.

$ vim .`zshrc`

$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

step 3 : source your .`zshrc` file

$ source ~/.`zshrc`

step 4 : execute "go env" command, you should be able to see local environment details.

$ go env

Answer (score 1):

try this if your device is a M chipset mac

```
export PATH = ${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin:${GOPATH}/bin/darwin_amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fish, add the following to your fish config found at `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
# Go
set -x PATH "/usr/local/go/bin" "$PATH"
```

After, be sure to relaunch Terminal or run `source ~/.config/fish/config.fish`