# Mockery not getting installed on mac

Tags: go

I tried installing mockery on mac with go
Command Tried: 
  go get -u github.com/vektra/mockery/
  go get -u github.com/vektra/mockery/cmd/mockery

Every-time the command completes without printing any thing on terminal.
When I try running command **mockery -version** it says command **mockery** not found.
Can any one tell me what is the process of installing mockery.

I am new to GO, and trying to learn things now.

Go environment

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/sumit.sinha/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/sumit.sinha/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace:"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.1/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.1/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace/wallet-ops-service/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/pk/mvyv162j29b5xf9m4tw28drht_lgvc/T/go-build619117997=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Show the output of `go env` command please.

Comment: Added in question

Comment: The `GOPATH` variable seems wrong, do you edit the `GOPATH` somewhere?

Comment: I edited it yeah, when i installed it, what is the correct value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command not found go — on Mac after installing Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708207/command-not-found-go-on-mac-after-installing-go)

Comment: No, this is not working I added the PATH in bash, still no.

Comment: the `go get ...` command installs packages in the `$GOPATH/bin`, what the output of `ls $GOPATH/bin` ?

Comment: /Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace:/Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace:/Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace:/Users/sumit.sinha/.go/bin

Comment: It's not how it should looks like.

Comment: Added this to path  "export PATH=$PATH:/Users/sumit.sinha/goWorkspace/bin" and it worked

Comment: Yeah, I added it multiple times, i will correct it. Thanks for your help on looking the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Missed adding path variable **$GOPATH/bin**.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative you can try. Exact steps will work for windows enviroment, with some change I believe it will work for Mac/Linux.

1. Download/Clone "mockery" from GitHub.
2. For windows, extract it in your "C:\Users\go\src".
3. Rename, extracted dir to "mockery" from "mockery-master", in case any error occurs related to name.
4. Traverse to dir "cmd/mockery", execute command `"go install mocker.go"`.
5. Check if binary is created in "C:\Users\go\bin" by the name "mockery", if not set GOBIN path from enviroment variables.
6. If everything will be good, this test will work `"mockery -name=your_interface_name"`

Hope it helps you :-)

Answer (score 0):

In windows,

1. Edit environtment variabel ( PATH )
2. Add "{your gopath location}/bin"